# Why are the icons not showing up on Firefox OS Simulator?

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

I just installed Firefox 33 and went to the simulator and the icons are not showing up. At work I downloaded it and it worked fine. I have tried to install twice and the same affect.

**How do I get the icons to show up on the simulator screen?**

[image: Firefox OS Simulator showing all apps with the samedefault icon]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a VERY old simulator build (1.1?). Use the App Manager or WebIDE (under Tools > Web Developer) and install the most recent version from there.

See also https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/10/introducing-the-firefox-os-app-manager/

Comment: Well. If I just want to install a new simulator i installed version 1.3 I have firefox os 33. Where is the WebIDE. I looked under tools and Web Developer and didn't see a specific WebIDE. There is Web Developer and then there is the Firefox OS Simulator. I just purchased a phone that runs the 1.3 os and want to use that to test. But I have not been able to get the device to show in the AppDevl Manager. Are there windows 7 drivers that have to be installed.

Comment: Which device are you using?